# Laravel selectRaw count where not working

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-8

I would like to get items where **used_items < limit** but i get also used_items >= limit.
I tired to try use having but didn't work either.

```
public function getAllowedItems()
{
    $items = Item::leftJoin('runners_items', 'runners_items.item_id', 'items.id')
        ->leftJoin('subrace_items', 'subrace_items.item_id', 'items.id')
        ->where('subrace_items.sub_race_id', $this->id)
        ->select('items.*', DB::raw('count(items.id)-1 as used_items'))
        ->where('items.limit', '>', 'used_items')
        ->orWhere('items.limit', 0)
        ->groupBy('items.id')->get();
    dd($items);
}
```

Comment: what type of error, you facing?

Comment: Any exception or error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this select query not work properly

```
->select('items.*', DB::raw('count(items.id)-1 as used_items'))
```

try this.it will work

```
  public function getAllowedItems()
    {
         $user_items =Item::leftJoin('runners_items','runners_items.item_id','items.id')
        ->leftJoin('subrace_items', 'subrace_items.item_id', 'items.id')
        ->where('subrace_items.sub_race_id', $this->id)
        ->select('items.*', DB::raw('count(items.id)-1 as used_items'))
        ->groupBy('items.id')->get();

   $user_item=$user_items[0]->user_items;

  $items = Item::leftJoin('runners_items','runners_items.item_id','items.id')
        ->leftJoin('subrace_items', 'subrace_items.item_id', 'items.id')
        ->where('subrace_items.sub_race_id', $this->id)
        ->select('items.*'))->where('items.limit', '>', $user_items)
        ->orWhere('items.limit', 0)
        ->groupBy('items.id')->get();
    dd($items);
        
    }
```